# Oracle APEX Show Custom Alert Message Using Page Item Value

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to create a DA in order to show as an alert the value of my item page P2003_TEMP_DOUBLE.
This value is not stored to any table in my database. The result of this action is a null alert!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the javascript api of oracle apex you must apply the bind variables in this way

```
alert( "P1_ITEM value = " +  apex.item( "P1_ITEM" ).getValue()  );
```

Ref. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/javascript_api.htm#AEAPI29472